# how to change http request timeout for locust HttpLocust

Tags: locust

Seems the default timeout is 60 second in FastHttpLocust and HttpLocust. Is there a way to change it? Here is my locust file:

```
from locust import TaskSet, task, between
from locust.contrib.fasthttp import FastHttpLocust

class HTTPGet(TaskSet):
    @task(1)
    def index(self):
        self.client.get("/")

class WebsiteUser(FastHttpLocust):
    task_set = HTTPGet
    host="http://www.google.com"
    wait_time = between(0.5, 0.5)
```

Answer (score 4):

In Locust 1.0 and later, you can use `network_timeout` and `connection_timeout` on `FastHttpLocust`.

See https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/increase-performance.html.

```py
class WebsiteUser(FastHttpLocust):
    network_timeout = 5.0
    connection_timeout = 5.0
```